# Label based indexing Pandas (.loc)

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I have recently been made aware of the dangers of chained assignment, and I am trying to use the proper method of indexing in pandas using loc[rowindex, colindex]. I am working with mixed data types (mix within the same series of np.float64 and list and string) - this is unavoidable. I have an integer index

I am running the following loop through a data frame

```
Count = 0
for row in DF.index:
print row
    if '/' in str(DF.order_no[row]) and '/' not in str(DF.buyer[row]) and '/' not in    str(DF.buyer[row])\
    and '/' not in str(DF.smv[row]) and '/' not in str(DF.item[row]):
        DF.loc[row, 'order_no'] = str(DF.loc[row, 'order_no']).split('/')
        Count +=1
```

Count

Which returns the error:

```
 TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Within that loop I can do:

```
print DF.loc[row, 'order_no']
```

and

```
print DF.loc[row, 'order_no'] == str(DF.loc[row, order_no]).split('/')
```

but not

```
DF.loc[row, 'order_no'] = str(DF.loc[row, order_no]).split('/')
```

Using the print statement I see that it gets stuck on row 3, yet:

```
DF.loc[3, 'order_no']
```

works just fine.

Help apprecitated.

EDIT

A workaround is the following:

```
Count = 0
Vals = []
Ind = []
for row in DF.index:
    if '/' in str(DF.order_no[row]) and '/' not in str(DF.buyer[row]) and '/' not in str(DF.buyer[row])\
    and '/' not in str(DF.smv[row]) and '/' not in str(DF.item[row]):
        Vals.append(DF.order_no[row].split('/'))
        Ind.append(row)
        Count +=1

DF.loc[Ind, 'order_no'] = Vals
```

In other words I can create a list of the values to be modified and then change them using .loc. This works fine which leads me to believge that the issue is not with the values I am tryng to assign, and with the assignment process itself.

Here is an example of the type of data I am working on: The code fails on row 3 and 9 as far as i can tell. Sorry its in csv format, but this is how I am reading it into pandas.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zuy8pj15nlhmcfb/EG2.csv

Using that data if the following is done:

```
EG = pd.reas_csv('EG.csv')
EG.loc[3, 'order_no'] = str(EG.loc[3, 'order_no']).split('/')
```

Fails with the error

`object of type 'int' has no len()`

But

```
EG['order_no'][3] = str(EG.loc[3, 'order_no']).split('/')
```

works fine, but this is the type of chain assignment I am trying to avoid as it was giving me issues elsewhere.

which is why I thought this was just a syntax error.

Sorry for this now unweildy question

Comment: Does `DF.loc[3, 'order_no'] = str(DF.loc[3, order_no]).split('/')` work?  If not, the problem is probably with the value you are trying to assign.  Print it out and see what it is, and compare it to values you successfully assign on other iterations.

Comment: No it does not work, and its not because of the value I am assigning, as I can inspect that value and assign it directly. Indeed the way I have got around the problem is to create a series of the new values indexed as per the loop and the afterwards assign the values. But for some weird reason the assingment inside the loop always fails.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean by "inspect that value and assign it directly".  Can you provide sample data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Basically I can confirm that the issue is not with the value I am trying to assing. See the edit above:

Comment: Can you provide sample data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Your workaround is not the same, since in your original code you assign the value `str(DF.loc[row, 'order_no']).split('/')`, but in the workaround you assign `DF.order_no[row].split('/')[0]`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is true, my mistake. It works the same either way

Comment: OK, now I am really confused. I sliced the data frame to include the first point at which the code breaksdown, to supply as example data, and it works fine on that data. But it still does not work on the data frame I am actually working on.

Comment: Until you give us a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that we can copy and paste -- @BrenBarn asked for a sample dataframe multiple times -- you're significantly limiting the pool of people who can help.  (Many people often ignore questions which aren't SSCCE, as there are more than enough questions which are to keep us busy.)

Comment: Easy dude, he asked once. I'm totally happy to supply an example, I'm just trying to work out how to get the data in here.

Comment: @WoodyPride: respectfully, that's what you do *before* you ask a question.  Also: he asked twice.  See the comment starting "Sorry, I don't get"; and then he politely repeats exactly the same thing immediately thereafter.

Comment: Yup, thought this one could just be a syntax error on my part. I know the value of examples. When one was called for I had to spend 10 mins anonymising the data, as it is confiedential.

Comment: @WoodyPride Could you try for a smaller example? Personally I think it's annoying to diagnose atm as there's too much noise (e.g. drop the columns you're not using, some of the rows that aren't raising, make the line with the ands have fewer conditions) Ideally smaller than a 5 by 5 :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have now restricted the data to only the coloumns necesssary.

Comment: @AndyHayden shortest test case possible: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'working_hr': {3: 9.0}, 'order_no': {3: 731231}}).loc[3, 'order_no'] = [1,2]`; Woody, you can edit your question with this test case if you wish. It reflects your error.

Comment: @AndyHayden The reason is that value is treated as list, and OP wan't to set it as scalar. Inspecting code, can't see how can this error be avoided with indexer setter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be running into dtype issues.  The following code works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'working_hr': {3: 9.0}, 'order_no': {3: 731231}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, dtype=object)
```

And then:

```
>>> df.loc[3, 'order_no'] = [1, 2]
>>> df
  order_no working_hr
3   [1, 2]          9
```

Note the `dtype=object`.  This may be why your errors disappeared when you shortened the DataFrame, especially if you're reading from csv.  In many situations (such as readng from CSV), pandas tries to infer the dtype and pick the most specific one.  You can assign a list as a value if the dtype is object, but not if it's (for instance) float64.  So check whether your mixed-type column really is set to dtype `object`.

The same works with your provided CSV:

```
>>> df = pandas.read_clipboard(sep='\t', index_col=0)
>>> df
        buyer          order_no                                 item         smv
0         H&M            992754                        Cole tank top        6.17
1         H&M            859901                         Thilo Bottom        8.55
2         H&M            731231               Palma Short Sleeve Tee        5.65
3         H&M     731231/339260                      Palma Price Tee        5.65
4         H&M     859901/304141  Thilo Paijama Set top/Elva Tank Top   5.80/5.58
5         H&M            768380                       Folke Tank Top           6
6         H&M     596701/590691                        Paul Rock Tee        7.65
7    H&M/Mexx  731231/KIEZ-P002        Palma Short Sleeve Tee/Shorts  5.65/12.85
8         NaN               NaN                                  NaN         NaN
9  Ginatricot     512008/512009                           J.Tank top         4.6
>>> df.loc[3, 'order_no'] = str(df.loc[3, 'order_no']).split('/')
>>> df
        buyer          order_no                                 item         smv
0         H&M            992754                        Cole tank top        6.17
1         H&M            859901                         Thilo Bottom        8.55
2         H&M            731231               Palma Short Sleeve Tee        5.65
3         H&M  [731231, 339260]                      Palma Price Tee        5.65
4         H&M     859901/304141  Thilo Paijama Set top/Elva Tank Top   5.80/5.58
5         H&M            768380                       Folke Tank Top           6
6         H&M     596701/590691                        Paul Rock Tee        7.65
7    H&M/Mexx  731231/KIEZ-P002        Palma Short Sleeve Tee/Shorts  5.65/12.85
8         NaN               NaN                                  NaN         NaN
9  Ginatricot     512008/512009                           J.Tank top         4.6
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you! That has worked. Funny thing is, my data was showing as dtype object, but declaring it when reading the csv seems to have solved the problem. Thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter error raising code for reference (until OP includes it in his question):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'working_hr': {3: 9.0}, 'order_no': {3: 731231}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.loc[3, 'order_no'] = [1,2] # raises error
```

Inspecting code, list value `[1,2]` is treated by _setitem_with_indexer as list, and I can't see how can this issue be avoided for the value treated as scalar.

Comment: Thanks so much, it looks like the BrenBarn answer has taken your example and made it work by delaring the dtype. Thanks!